# Wpf - popup issue inside Usercontrol when click on button

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Window page, after click a button from window page --> then a UserControl page showing. After Inside UserControl there is a `<Popup Name="MyPopup">` popup. The Popup always stays on top problem. How can I solve this issue ?

I have tried,

```html
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="Green">
    <Grid >
        <Button Height="50" Width="100" Content="window_ClickMe" Click="btnUserManage_Click"></Button>
          <ContentControl Name="cont2" Visibility="Hidden">
          
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
    
</Window>
```

and code behind page of window,

```
private void btnUserManage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UC_UserMgmt mw = new UC_UserMgmt();
        cont2.Content = mw;
        cont2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

then, this is usercontrol page with popup,

```html
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UC_UserMgmt"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400" Background="Blue">
 
        <Grid>
        <Grid Name="g1">
            <Button Content="usercontrol_ClickMe" Height="50" Width="150" Margin="150,0,0,250" Click="btnShow_Click"></Button>
           
        </Grid>
               <Popup Name="MyPopup" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              HorizontalOffset="-150" Placement="Mouse" StaysOpen="{Binding ElementName=g1,Path=IsMouseOver}"
               VerticalOffset="20"
               AllowsTransparency="True">
        <StackPanel>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" Background="Brown" BorderThickness="1" Width="300" Height="100" >
                <Grid>
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtUName" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="28" Width="223" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,26,64.6,0" />
                    <Button Content="Open" Height="30" Width="50" Margin="238,24,9.6,43.6" Click="btnOpen_Click"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and this is code behind page of usercontrol,

```
private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         MyPopup.IsOpen = true;
         System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog fDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
         fDialog.Title = "Select file to be zip";
         if (fDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
         {
             txtUName.Text = fDialog.FileName.ToString();
         }
    }  

    private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyPopup.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

The problem is, when user click on OPEN button, an openFileDialog is opening and when it is opened, the popup seems disappear. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe using Popup is not the right choice in your situation. Take a look at [Popup.StaysOpen Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.staysopen(v=vs.110).aspx), in particular the part that says

> When the StaysOpen property is set to true, Popup stays open until it is explicitly closed by setting the IsOpen property to false. When StaysOpen is false, the Popup control intercepts all mouse and keyboard events to determine when one of these events occurs outside the Popup control.

I can't think of a clean way of keeping that popup open when showing the dialog box, because the dialog box is going to create a mouse/keyboard event when you interact with it

But to answer your question, I can think of two choices

1) You can simply move `MyPopup.IsOpen = true;` in `btnOpen_Click` to the end of the code block. I assume this will cause the popup to reopen after the dialog box is closed

2) You can create a boolean property or dependency property in your code behind set it to true when showing the popup and bind your Popup's **StaysOpen** to it, and maybe set it to false in **LostFocus** for **g1** or something like that. Or even set **StaysOpen** to **true** and use **IsOpen** to close your Popup in **g1**'s **LostFocus**

**Edit - Second Solution How-To** *Don't use it, dirty code, bad practices, and the popup remains on top of dialogbox*

In the Popup set `StaysOpen="True"`
In every control in the UserControl except the UserControl itself and the textbox set `Focusable="False"`
Add `private bool dont;` to the UserControl's code-behind and set it to **True** in the beginning of `btnOpen_Click` and set it to **False** in its end
In the UserControl and the TextBox add `LostFocus="UserControl_LostFocus"`
And then add this function in UserControl code-behind

```
private void UserControl_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!dont && !txtUName.IsFocused && !IsFocused)
        MyPopup.IsOpen = false;
}
```

Comment: Sir, excuse me! I can't get clear idea from your 2nd advice. Could you please explain by some example? and here also I am facing another problem, that is, I can not centralize the position of popup. It is changing every time its position after populate.

Comment: @AbhiJA The reason for your popup's position changing everytime is because you've set `Placement="Mouse"` change it to `Placement="Bottom"` or any option that is static like that and fits your design. If you want the position to be relative to something other than its parent use `PlacementTarget`. About the code sample you'll have to give me a couple of hours

Comment: Sure Sir! Thanks. I will wait for your answer reply also will try my side also. Thank you once again.

Comment: The popup's position changing issue is solved. Thanks.

Comment: @AbhiJA I managed to write some code that works, but the issue is if you keep the popup visible when showing the dialogbox it remains on top of the dialogbox. Maybe the first solution is better. If you still want to do the second one I'm editing my answer to add the code in the end

Comment: Hello Pouya Sir, I did fix the issue. After click on open button then I ahve set inside button click MyPopup.IsOpen = false; again added file path inside textbox then I have set MyPopup.IsOpen = true; Now its working fine with help of your advice. Thank once again.